# Inconsistent selection in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm seeing some funny behavior in Pandas indexing. By way of example, suppose I create a `Panel`

```
p = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(3,6,9))
```

and index it in various ways.

```
p.iloc[1,1,1].shape == ()
p.iloc[1,1,:].shape == (9,)
p.iloc[1,:,1].shape == (6,)
p.iloc[1,:,:].shape == (6,9)
p.iloc[:,1,1].shape == (3,)
p.iloc[:,1,:].shape == (9,3)   # confusing
p.iloc[:,:,1].shape == (6,3)   # confusing
p.iloc[:,:,:].shape == (3,6,9)
```

In the lines marked as "confusing", it seems that Pandas is transposing the `DataFrame` to reverse the order of the dimensions after it does the indexing. Why does it do this? Is there a way to stop it?

The same thing happens if I start with a `Panel4D`:

```
p = pd.Panel4D(np.random.rand(3,6,9,12))

p.iloc[1,1,1,1].shape == ()
p.iloc[1,1,1,:].shape == (12,)
p.iloc[1,1,:,1].shape == (9,)
p.iloc[1,1,:,:].shape == (9,12)  # ok
p.iloc[1,:,1,1].shape == (6,)
p.iloc[1,:,1,:].shape == (12,6)  # confusing
p.iloc[1,:,:,1].shape == (9,6)   # confusing
p.iloc[1,:,:,:].shape == (6,9,12)
p.iloc[:,1,1,1].shape == (3,)
p.iloc[:,1,1,:].shape == (12,3)  # confusing
p.iloc[:,1,:,1].shape == (9,3)   # confusing
p.iloc[:,1,:,:].shape == (3,9,12)
p.iloc[:,:,1,1].shape == (6,3)   # confusing
p.iloc[:,:,1,:].shape == (3,6,12)
p.iloc[:,:,:,1].shape == (3,6,9)
p.iloc[:,:,:,:].shape == (3,6,9,12)
```

It seems that the strange behavior occurs whenever there are two slice indices, one of which is in the first two positions.

Of course this does not occur when using a plain `ndarray` from NumPy.

Comment: That is kinda weird. Neat find. Perhaps something to do with how the shape algorithm orders its variables.

Comment: IMO this would be better as a github issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues. I think this is a bug in the Panel4D code base, I don't think this part of pandas has enough love :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report for pandas https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: @AndyHayden I posted here because it's not at all clear (to me) that this is a bug. But if it is, I agree.

Comment: @DavidZ I think it most likely is, this behaviour should be the same as numpy!